# Copy post content as markdown -- quick and easy way to quote people!

Tags: script, markdown

This is a userscript that converts the selected text to Markdown and allows you to quickly copy it.

It is mainly useful for when copying from comments on posts, where you want to quote the user, or even quoting from a post.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> (`m` for `m`arkdown) to show the prompt for you to copy

Example:

> This **is** a *test* of the [markdown converter](http://stackapps.com)
>
> (the source: `This <b>is</b> a <i>test</i> of the <a href='http://stackapps.com'>markdown converter</a>`)

gets converted to for you to copy:

`This **is** a _test_ of the [markdown converter](http://stackapps.com)`

It uses the [to-markdown](https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown/) converter.

### Install it from [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/9203772dd22c4bc04aafebd4fc4f8ca1/raw/6915e47aaad948502d1448b4d73f91b67f981cc9/markdownCopier.user.js)

(or [view source](https://gist.github.com/shu8/9203772dd22c4bc04aafebd4fc4f8ca1))

It's only been tested on Chrome, so please post bugs/feature requests here :)

Comment: This script is buggy; not clear where to report details.  It conflicts with at least some SOX features, like fixing the top bar (that just disappeared), and I was unable to use this comment box with it enabled (clicking Add Comment just reloaded the page).  Looks like a potentially useful script, though.

Comment: @fixer1234 I can't reproduce the top bar thing, but I can reproduce the comment bug -- I'll try and fix this ASAP :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: Thanks for the scripts!  I am also unable to use the comment box with it enabled. The inbox and achievements button in the top bar also don't seem to work with this script.

Comment: @fixer1234 *1 year later...* it's fixed! sorry for the delay

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt fixed :) please can you reinstall?

Comment: This was a little confusing, but it worked.  It would be helpful to add an instruction that it's a two-step process: ctrl-alt-M, then ctrl-C on the pop-up.  The ctrl-C instruction looked like either advice of revision to the interface, or going back to the original comment to do it as a second step.

Comment: Bad news.  Just discovered that it is still interfering with comments.  Was just on a thread with a long comment history, with the last comments replaced with the "N more comments" placeholder.  Nothing would display the additional comments until I disabled this script.

Comment: @fixer1234 weird, can't repro on chrome, probably another FF thing ;( *sighs and opens FF again :P*

Comment: Can't delete comments with this enabled either...

Comment: It looks like this script does not work anymore (Chrome 101). This one works for me: [Get Comment markdown, copy comment code to clipboard](https://stackapps.com/q/8296/21874)

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Thanks for letting me know -- it should be fixed now! :)

Comment: Thank you. It works again. Just a note about the installation URL: for the installation the URL always pointing to the latest commit should be used otherwise Tampermonkey cannot update the script. Just remove the commit ID from the URL: `https://gist.github.com/shu8/9203772dd22c4bc04aafebd4fc4f8ca1/raw/markdownCopier.user.js`