# Get Comment markdown, copy comment code to clipboard

Tags: script, comments, editing, markdown

#### About:

This userscript adds flyover buttons to every comment to fetch that comment's code (markdown).

Reference [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382478/access-to-the-source-of-comment), and [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295931/how-do-i-view-the-source-code-of-a-comment) on Meta Stack Overflow.

#### Features:

- The **markdown is paste-ready** for use in a post or in another comment.
- Handy **clipboard button** copies the source straight to your clipboard.
- Open-source and hosted on GitHub.
- Has full API error handling.

#### Screenshot:

> [image: screenshot of comment markdown display]

#### Platform:

This is a userscript that runs in your browser.  It requires a userscript extension like *Tampermonkey* or *Violentmonkey*.

#### Install button: <kbd>[Install from GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%2C%20View%20Comment%20source%20markdown_code.user.js)</kbd>

#### Code:

The code is [on GitHub, in the BrockA/SE-misc repository](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange%2C%20View%20Comment%20source%20markdown_code.user.js).

Post bug reports and pull requests there. <sup><sub>(Or below if you don't do GitHub.)</sub></sup>

**Known issues:**

- The [API has no support for *Area 51*](https://stackapps.com/questions/4590/is-there-any-support-for-area-51-in-the-new-api), so this script will not work there.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the `StackExchange.helpers.show*` functions!! :D

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, you're welcome. See also https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/js/stub.js.

Comment: This doesn't work in greasemonkey - `StackExchange` is not defined.

Comment: @ekhumoro, [Greasemonkey 4+ is majorly fubar](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html); I no longer support GM.  Switch to a different engine if you want to use this script.